# How to use cp from stdin?

Tags: cygwin, stdin, cp

#### Note:

`# cat /tmp/foo` - regular file

```
/lib/a.lib
/lib/b.lib
/lib/c.lib
/lib/d.lib
```

---

`cat /tmp/foo | xargs cp /tmp/fred`

**cp: target /lib/d.lib is not a directory**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

xargs normally places its substituted args last. You could just do:

```
$ cp `cat /tmp/foo` /tmp/fred/.
```

If it's really just the lib files, then `cp /lib/?.lib /tmp/fred/.` would naturally work.

And to really do it with `xargs`, here is an example of putting the arg first:

```
0:~$ (echo word1; echo word2) | xargs -I here echo here how now
word1 how now
word2 how now
0:~$
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `/tmp/fred` is a directory, specify it using the `-t` (`--target-directory` option):

```
$ cat /tmp/foo | xargs cp -t /tmp/fred
```

Answer (score 3):

Your version of xargs probably accepts `-I`:

```
xargs -I FOO cp FOO /tmp/fred/ < /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Sinan Ünür

```
cat /tmp/foo | xargs cp -t /tmp/fred
```

if no -t support

```
( cat /tmp/foo; echo /tmp/fred ) | xargs cp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like:

```
cp /lib/*.lib /tmp/fred
```

I think your command is failing because xargs creates the following command:

```
cp /tmp/fred /lib/a.lib /lib/b.lib /lib/c.lib /lib/d.lib
```

That is, it ends up trying to copy everything to /lib/d.lib, which is not a directory, hence your error message.

Answer (score 0):

The destination directory needs to be the last thing on the command line, however `xargs` appends stdin to the end of the command line so in your attempt it ends up as the first argument.

You could append the destination to /tmp/foo before using xargs, or use cat in backticks to interpolate the sorce files before the destination:

```
    cp `cat /tmp/foo` /tmp/fred/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming /tmp/fred is a directory that exists, you could use a while loop

```
while read file
do
    cp $file /tmp/fred
done < /tmp/foo
```